# android viewgroup layoutparams in xml

Tags: android, android-layout

Do I need to make a reference somewhere to let the designer know which layoutparams the parent has?

I have made a layout object based on viewgroup. That is working. But when I add views to the layout (in xml mode), then I don't see the layout properties like "layout width" and "layout height". (the "Misc" part of the properties). But what i can do is just type somthing like: `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` in the xml textview instead of the designview. That is working fine.

I don't have any custom layout properties, i just want the basic layout properties.

how can the layoutparams be dispayed in the designer?

Comment: You have problems not with Android, but with GUI. Tag you question correctly and write in text - what IDE do you use? --- Put here the whole XML file, please.

Answer (score 0):

It is not usual to use ViewsGroup in the layout xml. In Eclipse, ViewsGroup is not included in the list of the possible root layouts by the wizard. So, I think, it is not supported in that role. Better use merge, or FrameLayout, if you want something primitive.